# Print object ids in logback log or stacktrace in java

Tags: java, debugging, stack-trace, logback, dalvik

Is there any way to get Java or [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) to give my the object id (or address or whatever) in stack traces and log calls. In other words, instead of this:

```
com.example.MyObject
```

in my stack traces I want this:

```
com.example.MyObject@123456
```

And for logging, I want this:

```
LOG.debug("A message");
```

to act like this:

```
LOG.debug(this + ": A message");
```

I can't see a way to do it though, because both Logback and java itself seem to use `StackTraceElement`s, and those don't record this information.

For bonus points, how is `Object.toString()` implemented in dalvik? The generic java docs say it is `toHex(Object.hashCode())` but I tested that and it doesn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note, stack traces per se don't contain references to the `this` in each frame. That info *is* available, though, to a debugger. There is probably a hacky way to get the info you want, but it'd be ugly, slow, and probably flaky. Honestly, I wouldn't bother.

> For bonus points, how is `Object.toString()` implemented in dalvik?

Here's (something like) tip-of-tree of `Object.java`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/bcf0a81a927992883f0cb49c1c945141d1261b8b/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/Object.java

From there:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Note that this is the base implementation in the class `Object`, but it is commonly overridden in subclasses. This may explain whatever difference you may have seen.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm weird, I did a test with a plain `Object` and `Integer.toHexString(hashCode())` and I didn't get the same value... Oh well. I guess I will give up and just add `+ this` to all my debug statements.